# Getting items from one table that don't have a corresponding foreign key in another table

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hi I am working on a react app that is on a ruby on rails server setup, that uses postgres.

I have two tables in the database, movies and genres. In the movie table, there is a field genre id. And in the genre table its ID is how it links to movie table's genre id. I am trying to find all genres that don't have a corresponding id listed in the movie table. I have tried two different ways, with SQL directly.

```
sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM genres
       LEFT JOIN movies
       ON genres.id = movies.genre_id
       WHERE genre.id = movies.genre"
        
genres_with_no_movie = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql).rows[0][0]
```

The ruby on rails way.

```
genres_with_no_movie = Genre.joins(:movies).count()
```

Both of these give me the number of connections. It gives me places where a movie does have a corresponding genre. I am trying to find genres that don't have a movie that connects. I tried WHERE NOT EXISTS in place of where and that did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM genres
     WHERE id not in
      (SELECT genre_id FROM movies)

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` allows you to retrieve the rows from the table genres and which have no correspondance in movies, ie movies.genre IS NULL :

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM genres
LEFT JOIN movies
ON movies.genre_id = genres.id
WHERE movies.genre IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative perhaps quicker, and (imho more direct) uses NOT EXISTS instead of join.

```
select count(*) 
  from genres g
 where not exists 
       (select null 
          from movies m 
         where m.genre_id = g.id
       );
```